# Destructuring return in Kotlin without val or var

Tags: kotlin

I see that I can return a tuple with destructuring:

```
fun getPair() = Pair(1, "foo")

var (num, str) = getPair()
```

Is there any way to use `getPair` without using `val` or `var`?

This don't work:

```
(num, str) = getPair()
```

Comment: Nope, you need val or var

Comment: Relevant issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11362?_ga=2.2512179.2076737493.1598447399-370803150.1565276011

Comment: You could pass the result to another function, e.g. `println(getPair())`.  Or you could call a method on it, e.g. `getPair().let{ /* … */ }`.  Or you could use it in an expression, e.g. `if (getPair().first > 10)`.  Or anywhere else you can use a value!  But I suspect that's not quite what you're asking about…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A destructering declaration destructures a complex object into one or more variables. If we would not use `val` and `var` Kotlin would not know in what variable to put the destructured object.

So no, you need to define a `val` or `var` type.